# What is the conditional probability that Taster 2’s rating is higher than 3 when Taster 1's rating is a 3?

Tags: probability, statistics

If Taster 1’s rating for a wine is 3, what is the conditional probability that Taster 2’s rating is higher than 3?

```
     1        2      3       4       5 
1   0.03    0.02    0.01    0.00    0.00
2   0.02    0.08    0.05    0.02    0.01 
3   0.01    0.05    0.25    0.05    0.01 
4   0.00    0.02    0.05    0.20    0.02 
5   0.00    0.01    0.01    0.02    0.06
```

Taster 2 is the horizontal columns and Taster 1 is the vertical columns.
I know to find P(B|A) = 0.06/P(Taster 1 rating 3).

I've tried P(B|A) = 0.06 / 0.01 = 6 which makes no sense
I also did P(B|A) = 0.06 / 3(for rating of 3) = 0.02 
I'm not sure what the probability of Taster 1 rating a 3 is...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are $5$ things that could have happened with the given information. Taster $1$ gives a $3$, then taster $2$ gives a $1$, etc.

Then find the probability that taster $2$ rates a $4$ or $5$, $.06$, then divide by $.01+.05+.25+.05+.01=.37$ to get $.06/.37=\dots$